# Hint for sobolev norm inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I wish to find $C>0$ such that
$$|f(1/3)| \leq C\|f\|_{W^{1,2}[0,1]},$$
for all $f$ in the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}[0,1]$.

The context is that $\rho(f)=|f(1/3)|$ defines a norm on the space of zero degree polynomials on the unit interval. If we can find such constant above then by a theorem we may conclude
$$\rho’(f):=\left(|f(1/3)|^2 + \int_0^1 |f(x)|^2 dx \right)^{1/2}$$
is a norm on $W^{1,2}$ equivalent to the standard Sobolev norm. But I am absolutely stumped on finding this constant. I’ve tried to do a proof by contradiction and modeled after a similar inequality involving Sobolev/$L^p$ norms, but I cannot pinpoint the exact argument.

This *is* for homework, so please hints only.

Comment: The hint is always $f(1/3) - f(x) = \int_{1/3}^x f'(s) ds$.

Comment: @ArcticChar this is indeed what I considered for a direct proof! It must have just been too late last night. I will try again now. Thank you.